# Can I set an attached device as default launch target?

Tags: android, eclipse

In Eclipse I am developing an application using [Google APIs (maps)](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/index.html) on a Nexus One.
 When I launch the application for debugging on the device i get:

> "Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please
>   select a target device."

and the "Android Device Chooser" pops up.
I can select the Nexus One and everything is ok. It annoys me, however, that i need to select the device every time i want to test something.

Setting a build target name to any standard android version (not using Google apis) automatically launches my app without showing the Android Device Chooser. But since i need the maps, that is not an option for me.

Is there a way to force an application using Google apis, to be launched on the attached device without showing the Android Device Chooser?

Comment: Using Automatic works on my system but I use a G1.

Comment: I have the same problem, using HTC Desire. Answer below isn't working for me

Comment: I had two projects. One launched on my Xoom correctly, the other always prompted. Turns out selecting a build target of "Android 3.0" works automatically, "Google APIs" always prompts for me. That won't help you, but might help other people looking at this question who aren't bound to the Google API target.

Comment: It's the "Google APIs" target that causes this issue for me. On all 3 Android devices I have, from versions 2.1 to 2.3. I get this dialog every single time.

Answer (score 4):

Go to your project properties. Select `Run/Debug Settings`, click the `Edit` button of your run configuration, select the `Target` tab in the upcoming dialog, switch the selectboxes to "Automatic" and check the checkbox by your device.

Comment: Isn't changing anything for me. Is still displaying the same error for me. Using HTC Desire

Answer (score 3):

This is an irritating acknowledged defect ([Issue 11373](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11373)) reported on the [Android Issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list).

The Issue has status **Assigned** and presumably will be fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this; I should have just searched the issue tracker. Good to know it's been acknowledged by them at least.

Comment: Hope it will be fixed in a reasonable amount time.

Comment: Issue #11373 was marked as released in r16 back in March 2012. I don't recall the behavior ever changing, but if it has, it's regressed.

Answer (score 0):

I was just having this problem and traced it to my USB connection. I had started using a 2.0 hub, which I would think to be sufficient. It's powered. When I plugged the USB cable into the laptop itself, problem solved.

Good luck.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful to you.

> First Find the Your device OS Version & API Level.
>
> IN Eclipse, Then Right click on Your project select Property, In
>   Property's window select Android, In it select Project Build Target as
>   per your device OS API Level.
>
> For example i have Samsung Galaxy Fit - Android 2.2 os API Level - 8
>   so i,selected the  Google APIs, Google Inc, 2.2, 8 .

Let me know this is useful for you or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Once the popup comes up to choose a device, select your device and then check the `Use same device for future uses` at the button of the Dialog.