# No laucher activity found! Android Widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm new to widgets in Android and while looking around noticed that people unchecked the "Create Activity" setting when they first created their project for widgets, so I did the same. Now, when I run my widget I get this error:

```
[2013-10-04 18:08:35 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-10-04 18:08:35 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-10-04 18:08:35 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Performing sync
[2013-10-04 18:08:35 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
```

I'm now thinking that I should have kept the "Create Activity" setting checked. Would this be the issue? If so, how can I change the "Create Activity" setting?

Here is my Android Manifest by the way:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name=".AwesomeFileBuilderWidget" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget_stuff"/>

   <activity android:name=".WidgetConfig" android:label="@string/app_name">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
       </intent-filter>
   </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

This is the full error I get when I try to run my widget on a real device:

```
[2013-10-04 19:02:33 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] ------------------------------
[2013-10-04 19:02:33 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Android Launch!
[2013-10-04 19:02:33 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] adb is running normally.
[2013-10-04 19:02:33 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-10-04 19:02:33 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-10-04 19:02:33 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Performing sync
[2013-10-04 19:02:33 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2013-10-04 19:02:46 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Uploading AwesomeFileBuilderWidget.apk onto device 'HT18YMA05067'
[2013-10-04 19:02:51 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Failed to install AwesomeFileBuilderWidget.apk on device 'HT18YMA05067': timeout
[2013-10-04 19:02:51 - AwesomeFileBuilderWidget] Launch canceled!
```

Here are my classes and xml files:
AFBWidget.java:

```
import java.util.Random;

import com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget.R;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class AFBWidget extends AppWidgetProvider{

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    Random r = new Random();
    int randomInt = r.nextInt(1000000000);
    String rand = String.valueOf(randomInt);

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        int awID = appWidgetIds[i];
        RemoteViews v = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        v.setTextViewText(R.id.tvwidgetUpdate, rand);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(awID, v);
    }

}
```

Widget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvConfigInput"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bwidgetOpen"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvwidgetUpdate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Widgetconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etwidgetconfig"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bwidgetconfig"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

NOTE: This widget is not completely finished however, I should still be able to download my current widget to the homescreen, even if the widget doesn't have any functionality yet.

Answer (score 1):

When you do not have a launcher activity, the build environment does not know how to start your application. Thus, you get the error.

As stated in the second message,

> The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

That basically means that you need to add the widget to your homescreen by yourself, the application should get installed/updated by the build system.

---

The real issue is the last line

> Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.

You should try selecting a target device manually in your IDE, there might also be versioning issues between your app and the emulator/device you're using for debugging. A common issue is the use of google APIs, which require a real device with the google components installed, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243651/can-i-set-an-attached-device-as-default-launch-target).

Comment: I selected a target device via a real device from the selection menu that pops up now I get this error (please check updated question)

Answer (score 1):

Android needs a launcher to know what to use to start your app. A lot of what you have seen is probably people writing widget libraries. A library does not need a launcher because you use libraries by importing them into your app which Will have a launcher.

If you want to test your widget (which is what I think you're getting at) you will need to specify a launcher with something like:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.soundconception.tabbedslider.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I defined the intent-filer in my receiver but maybe I did it wrong? Or do I have to use an activty?

Comment: 1) You need something running that's going to call up this widget. Whether that's a MainActivity for your project, or something else that's going to call it.  2) As dst highlighted, you seem to have a problem getting the apk onto the device. Can you get this working on the emulator?

Comment: To re-respond:
1) I added my current class to the question, please take a look.

Comment: 2) (sorry for late response) I still get the same errors when I try to run my widget on the emulator, and not only that but I don't see my widget in the emulators list of widgets (on Nexus 4) but I don't think that really matters because when I run it on a real device, my widget shows up but I just get that error.

Comment: I FINALLY FIXED IT AFTER 3 DAYS! Ok, so it was indeed because my two java classes were in a default package. So to fix that, since my classes were being accessed via a different package, I created a new package that was my app (com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget) and then moved the classes into there and now it works with no problemos! :DD Thanks for all you've done I really do apperciate it!